# How do I get the header content for a DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter control template?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, controltemplate

```
<dg:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
    <dg:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource= ??? />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Template>
</dg:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to create/get/override content, if so, then use HeaderTemplate:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>  
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="part one"/>
                <TextBlock Text="part one"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding someValueInYourList}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```